# Why I cannot use the Fn + (up) to control the brightness?

Tags: 13.10, intel-graphics, brightness, lenovo

I have a Lenovo zhaoyang K27 with Intel® HD Graphics 3000. Since I installed Ubuntu for the first time, about two years ago, I haven't been able to change the brightness by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>. I found a solution in the following command:

```
echo 1450 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

where 1450 is the brightness value. This is the only way I could find to change the brightness.

To set the *sound* by the function keys ( <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> )works well, only the brightness is the problem.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am in no way an expert but my best guess is that in windows that would work through a Lenovo driver that "translates" (sorry if this is not the correct term) the key combination to the change in brightness.

If my assumption is correct, you might be able to use `xbacklight -set 40` (where "40" represents the percentage of brightness - you can change this to whatever you want [see here for more details](http://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu/)) and assign you key binding of choice to it.

EDIT: The above will set the backlight temporarily. If you want this permanent, you need to add this to start up (see link above). If you want to increase the brightness by, say 10% you can use `xbacklight -inc 10` or `xbacklight -dec 10` to decrease it.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to set the keybindings and I don't want to misinform you , but the "Custom Shortcuts" section [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings) might be a good place to start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for xbacklight. Saved a lot of my time. used custom shortcut to map fn+arrow keys :) thanks a ton!!